# Cell with a date in spanish format is copied as date with USA format

Tags: excel, vba

I have at source workbook and at target workbook a cell with date format, in spanish

01/05/2023 (May 1, 2023)

but when copy using VBA:

```
Private Sub Volcar(V As Integer)
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim K As Integer
    Limpiar False
    With Worksheets("Hoja1")
    Select Case V
    Case 1: K = (Num(ListaPedidos.ListIndex) - 1) * 14 + 2
    Case 2: K = ListaTodos.ListIndex * 14 + 2
    End Select
    .Range("B30").Value = Format(Hoja1.Cells(K, 1).Value, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End With
End Sub
```

it copy the date as 05/01/2023

Comment: `.Range("B30").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy" : .Range("B30").Value = CDate(Hoja1.Cells(K, 1).Value`)

Comment: Thanks, solved by myself. While writing the question, figure than both cells are Date, then why not copy directly ```.Range("B30").Value = Hoja1.Cells(K, 1).Value``` and work with this code